# How can I see the print() output immediately when running tests in PyCharm?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pycharm

**Context**

When I run tests in PyCharm, all `print()` output is delayed to show until the test finished.
I have long running tests, and would like to see some diagnostic `print()` during the run immediately

**Question**

How can I see the `print()` output immediately when running unit tests in PyCharm?

Comment: What about using logging instead for diagnostic?

Comment: Try JB_DISABLE_BUFFERING mentioned [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-22505) (can't test it myself)

Comment: I am going to try, it it works, this is definitely an answer. I also glad "I am not alone"